# Copy columns between tables in different servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Recently I moved **to** SQL Server 2012 **from** SQL Server 2005. Current scenario worked without any problem in SQL Server 2005.

> 1)Connect to server A
>
> 2)Open table X
>
> 3)Copy 3 columns(Clicking on Arrow in the designer and copy)
>
> 4)Connect to server B
>
> 5)Open table X in server B
>
> 6)Paste the columns (default values, descriptions and other things are
>   transferred automatically)-again clicking on the arrow

On SQL Server 2012 I can copy columns between tables only in the current server.

How can I achieve it between different servers? Is there any setting or something?

I'm really annoyed by this one. I worked for years like this and became a habit of mine.

**EDIT: I'm trying to copy columns definitions.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method to get the column definitions is to create a script and use the script on the other server.

```
In the Object Explorer navigate to the table that holds the columns. 
Right Click the table and select Script Table As. 
Select Create To. 
Select New Query Editor Window.
```

This will generate the SQL to create that table.

Select from that SQL, the column definitions you want and save the script. Execute the script on the other server.